# How to manage multiple ironpython versions?

Tags: python, github, virtualenv, ironpython, pyenv

I have the following issue: 
I have some software that installs a particular version of IronPython to GAC. But I need to install a newer version of IronPython without affecting GAC. Hence the need for somehow using pyenv on windows with IronPython.

I am not from a programming background, more of a brick and mortar background, so please bear with me here.

[pyenv-win][1] doesn't support IronPython yet, and given my background, I have no idea how to modify a GIT repository and then install it (I'm trying to learn all that, but first I need to set this environment up, so that I don't mess things up, its a vicious cycle :P).

I downloaded a copy of the code and I was looking into how it is addressing different python versions.

It seems in [this file][2]
there are variables: 
mirror, mirrorEnvPath, listEnv 
that point to location of the exe that pyenv-win is using to install and maintain python version

So I somehow need to add an iron python mirror location and another array to the list that reads something like this

```
ironmirror = "https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/download"
```

and add a line to listEnv

```
Array("ipy-2.7.9", ironmirror&"/ipy-2.7.9/", "IronPython-2.7.9.msi", "x64")_
```

That's how far I can get. If someone could help me put all this together, that would be nice. I have no idea how to run this modified code from my local hard drive. I would also like to somehow add this functionality to the package on GitHub as well so that others can use the same. Also, I am not sure if I am allowed to look into the code that others have shared and modify it. This is a new world for me. Apologies if that's the case.

Any help is appreciated.

> [1]: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win
>    [2]: https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win/blob/master/pyenv-win/libexec/pyenv-install.vbs